# Accessing Multipart Form Attribute Values - Vert.x / Quarkus

Tags: java, jax-rs, vert.x, quarkus

I would like to log all request calls, with theirs parameters, for a *REST* endpoint.

I started with the [`LoggingFilter` sample](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/master/rest-json-quickstart/src/main/java/org/acme/rest/json/LoggingFilter.java), but I'm having problems accessing the form attributes of a *multipart/form* request.

Here down a sample endpoint:

```java
@Path("/multipart-test")
@POST
@Consumes(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(TEXT_PLAIN)
public String multiPartTest(@MultipartForm MyForm form)
```

And here down the filter implementation:

```java
  @Context
  HttpServerRequest request;

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

      request.setExpectMultipart(true);
      request.endHandler(v -> {
          try {
              MultiMap formAttributes = request.formAttributes();
              System.out.println("formAttributes: " + formAttributes.entries().size());
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      });
  }
```

Here down the thrown exception:

> Unable to find contextual data of type: io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerRequest

Is there an tips to on how to access form attributes or should I use another approach to log the request with *multipart/form* data?

Comment: Hi Aguilar and welcome to SO.
Could you please update your `ContainerRequestFilter` implementation to provide the whole class?
You may also provide the whole stack trace.

Comment: hello, here there is the complete code
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/9284#issuecomment-628625084